# file_get_Contents won't send query strings in url , thus receiving nothing with $_GET

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a request to a website this way :

```
file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com/index.php?var=value');
```

in the index.php file ( Receiver )  , when I try to echo $_GET['var'] from within the index.php and get the response with file_Get_contents, I get nothing.
curl is getting it right , but I just want to know it this way in case curl is not installed

sender:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com/index.php?var=value');
```

receiver : 
index.php contains

```
<?php
echo $_GET['var'];
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried getting PHP to read the URL it is being requested from and parse the value out?

Comment: Please post more details (code and/or your system info).  I tested, and it sends the whole URL correctly.  I'm using PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: I printed  the data returned from the index.php which is the $_GET['var'] , but I got nothing

Comment: I've posted the code i'm using , please read my post again

Comment: @Naughty, there are two separate issues.  1. Is the request being sent correctly? 2. Is it being processed by the server correctly?  Use Wireshark or another tool to check the first.

Comment: Matthew Flaschen , thank you for your help :) I got it working now ..

Comment: Maybe you want to post what was wrong and how you ended up fixing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns the content of the file.

```
$var = file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com/index.php?var=value');
```

> The function returns the read data or
>   FALSE on failure. 
>   http://php.net

Comment: Alright you may confuse some things. Now i see you said receiver side, but the you say curl is getting it right. What curl would do on the receiver side? I don't get what you are after.

Comment: i've edited the question , please read it again to understand me better

Comment: is `allow_url_fopen = On` in your configuration? **Also, are you trying to fetch a local file or one with an url?**

Comment: i've just tested it right now and it works perfectly on my localhost.

Comment: it just returns true instead of the var query string , damn! what is wrong .. I'm fetching an online website

Comment: ohhhh , i'm an asshole ... sorry guys .. I figured that out

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your receiver...

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $uri["query"];
```